# Truecrypt: Encrypt 2 Windows systems on one hard drive

Tags: windows, truecrypt

I've got 2 Windows 7 Systems on one hard disk.

Is it possible and if so how can I encrypt both with TrueCrypt, so I can enter the password used for the first System to boot this one, or the second one to boot the second system?

There are no hidden volumes.
The Partition layout:

Partition 0: 100 MB System-reserved
Partition 1: 1 TB Windows 7 System 1 used for gaming
Partition 2: 1 TB Windows 7 System 2 used for work

Comment: I don't see any security concerns in this question - it's more of a software usage issue.  Though the software in question does serve a security purpose, questions like these are more appropriate for [su].  I will suggest migration - please don't cross-post.  Have you tried searching TrueCrypt's website?  Surely this isn't the first time this issue has come up.

Comment: All I could find refers to hidden volumes.

Comment: Related:  http://security.stackexchange.com/q/14227/953

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you are asking.  In order to do what you are contemplating Truecrypt would need to run BEFORE the OS (ie as part of the bootloader).  I am pretty sure there is no version which can run prior to the bootloader.

What you might be able to do is boot up with your Windows System, then have 2 Truecrypt volumes - 1 with your Work information and 1 with your gaming information and alternatively use each one.  This is not what you were asking, as (a) it is not "full disk" encryption - for example if a file is written outside the encrypted area it will be readable regardless of which partition is mounted and (b) it is possible to mount both partitions simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-operating-system

I think you need to reinstall one of the OS'es. As far as I remember, then one of the OS'es will be copied to the end of the harddisk (the hidden OS) and the other OS will be deleted.

When you start your computer, then the TrueCrypt bootloader will ask you for a password, based on what you type, then either the decoy OS or the hidden OS will start.

But because TrueCrypt "Hidden OS" feature is based on "plausible deniability", then this might not be what you're looking for (it has a few downsides, e.g the Hidden OS can't copy anything to USB sticks as a "security feature").